# How to add two 48bits hex number if I use ubyte array to store the numbers In C program

Tags: c, arrays, hex

Suppose I have two `ubyte` arrays initialized as

```
ubyte Hex_arr1[6] = {0xF6,0x31,0xA5,0x16,0x6B,0xE7}

ubyte Hex_arr2[6] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20}
```

How can I add this two array in C and store the result in `Hex_arr1`?

I cant simply add them bitwise as addition might have carry.So how to handle the carry?

Comment: For the arrays you show, what would be the result?

Comment: the result would be `Hex_arr1 = { 0xF6,0x31,0xA5,0x16,0x6C,0x07}`

Answer (score 3):

You do it the same way you'd do it on paper. You add the two right-most digits (after converting to a wider integer type that won't overflow), and store the least significant byte into the result. Then shift the previous sum down by one byte width (giving you the carry-in), and add the two 2nd-right-most digits to it, repeating the process until what you have left is the carry out the top of your 48-bit addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the carry, you can simply convert the arrays to two 64-bit unsigned integers, add them, and simply discard the top 16 bits.